# Create arrays with brace expansion in loop

Tags: shell-script, array, brace-expansion

I would like to generate a number of arrays that differ only by year. In the loop, I create the arrays with brace expansion and a variable.

I tried the following code without success:

```
LIST={JF,JFE,RFS,JBF,JFI,JMCB}
for year in {1998..2000} {2009..2011}
do
  declare -a 'y$year=('"$LIST"'-$year)'
  echo "${y$year[@]}"
done
```

The outcome should be the list of the following entries:

```
y1998: JF-1998 JFE-1998 RFS-1998 JBF-1998 JFI-1998 JMCB-1998
y1999: JF-1999 JFE-1999 RFS-1999 JBF-1999 JFI-1999 JMCB-1999
...
y2011: JF-2011 JFE-2011 RFS-2011 JBF-2011 JFI-2011 JMCB-2011
```

I don't need to print them, just use them in a loop as well as pass them as arguments. Because of the second, `eval` in the loop is not sufficient.

Comment: Why the hardquotes there? I think you might be trying too hard with the brace expansion...

Comment: The hardquotes, because I want to use the array in a loop while passing the entries as arguments.

Comment: Please explain in detail (i.e. with example values) what you want to happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deferring brace expansion is really a case for [`eval`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-eval), particularly if you want to stringify things  — [ordinary parameter expansion doesn't do the right thing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions) at the right time.

This should do what it seems you wanted:

```
LIST={JF,JFE,RFS,JBF,JFI,JMCB}
for year in {1998..2000} {2009..2011}
do
  eval "y$year=($LIST-$year)"
  tmp="y$year[@]"
  echo "${!tmp}"
done
```

<strike>You can't indirect into an array, so it's necessary to stringify the array inside an `eval` too if you want to print it out. If you don't, you can take out everything after the `;`.</strike> `tmp` is used for [indirect expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion): with `tmp` set to `"y$year[@]"`, where `$year` is replaced with its value, the expansion `${!tmp}` gives the contents of this iteration's array (what `${y1998[@]}`, etc, would have expanded to).

The above will output:

```
JF-1998 JFE-1998 RFS-1998 JBF-1998 JFI-1998 JMCB-1998
JF-1999 JFE-1999 RFS-1999 JBF-1999 JFI-1999 JMCB-1999
JF-2000 JFE-2000 RFS-2000 JBF-2000 JFI-2000 JMCB-2000
JF-2009 JFE-2009 RFS-2009 JBF-2009 JFI-2009 JMCB-2009
JF-2010 JFE-2010 RFS-2010 JBF-2010 JFI-2010 JMCB-2010
JF-2011 JFE-2011 RFS-2011 JBF-2011 JFI-2011 JMCB-2011
```

and also create arrays `y1998`...`y2011`. The `declare`s aren't strictly necessary, although they do let you skip an `eval` if you're aiming for that and don't need to stringify.

I suggest that this probably isn't the way you really want to achieve your underlying goal, though, whatever that is. Nested loops aren't evil, and if any bit of it's hardcoded you can abstract that out.

Comment: why do you not just `eval "y$year=...; echo \"\${y$year[@]}\""`? As written your command is susceptible to all kinds of unintended effects depending on the values of `$IFS` and filename expansion.

Comment: Minimising escaped characters. All of it is definitely not something you should generally want to do for those reasons and others, yes. If you have an odd enough `IFS` value you're on your own.

Comment: Yes, my intention is maybe not healthy, but everything works in my little script. What do you mean by `$IFS`?

Comment: If you have, say, `-` in `IFS` (the input field separator) everything gets cut up in the wrong place. The same happens if you have the default `IFS` and a space in one of your words.

Comment: You can indirect into an array, Michael. My own answer was screwed up because I suck at arrays, but I figured it out. You don't need `eval` for this - it is useful. I still think it's wrong that you don't quote where you should though - readability should not come before usability.

Comment: You can? I would often find that useful. `${!foo[@]}` is the obvious way but that's special-cased to keys.

Comment: You put the `[@]` as part of the value of the variable! That would be a better way of doing this, then.

Comment: I was talking about indirectly `declare`-ing. I know almost nothing about all the rest, but I do know that `declare "$arg=$still_the_same_arg"` is perfectly safely quoted, and that will still assign. What did you just figure out? Wait - is it kind of the same thing? Like `ref='foo[@]'; declare "\${!$ref}"` or something?

Comment: I meant, originally, that `${!foo[@]}` didn't give the values of the array named in `foo` in the way that indirection to a scalar does, and I discovered that `foo='bar[@]'` means that `${!foo}` does what I wanted.

Comment: Oh yeah - that's kinda cool - if a little weird. It does that as an arg to another command then? Apparently also in an assignment context... I wonder... at what point in the parse process then is `bash` handling the `!`? interesting...

Comment: You don't need `$tmp` - you already have `$year`... still, the quoting is better.

Comment: I didn't manage to make prefixing and suffixing work inside `${!...}`, which isn't to say it's not possible somehow.

Comment: Yeah - like `${#!var}` - I know. I've been playing with it for an hour, but without success.

Comment: I did arrive at a means of indirecting further into array members, if you care. You can't use the subscript, but you can... `a=( a b c ); b=( '' a[@] ); echo "${!b[1]:1:1}"` and similar. I only just learned that apparently `bash`'s associative arrays cannot contain indexed arrays - kind of a bummer, I guess. But something like that should alleviate it somewhat - if each subscript is another array name, for example.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way *(with brace expansion)*:

```
unset y _y
for y in {JF,JFE,RFS,JBF,JFI,JMCB,}-{{1998..2000},{2009..2011}}
do  case "${_y=y${y#*-}[@]}"               in 
    (y${y#-}*) echo "${!_y}"               ;; 
    (*)        declare -a "${_y%???}+=($y)";; 
esac; unset y _y; done
```

That will expand your parameter set for the `for` loop out to all of your desired values *plus* an extra last set which will consist only of the years. For each that does *not* begin with a digit `declare` adds an array member to whatever `y${y##*[!0-9]}` comes to, and for each that *does*, `echo` prints it.

So for the first 36 iterations it builds each array, and for the last 6 it prints each. The output is:

```
JF-1998 JFE-1998 RFS-1998 JBF-1998 JFI-1998 JMCB-1998
JF-1999 JFE-1999 RFS-1999 JBF-1999 JFI-1999 JMCB-1999
JF-2000 JFE-2000 RFS-2000 JBF-2000 JFI-2000 JMCB-2000
JF-2009 JFE-2009 RFS-2009 JBF-2009 JFI-2009 JMCB-2009
JF-2010 JFE-2010 RFS-2010 JBF-2010 JFI-2010 JMCB-2010
JF-2011 JFE-2011 RFS-2011 JBF-2011 JFI-2011 JMCB-2011
```

Here is an alternative, perhaps...

```
for year in 1998 1999 2000 2009 2010 2011
do  printf "%s-$year " JF JFE RFS JBF JFI JMCB
echo; done
```

That would at least get you the same output... 
To also store that in an array as well, probably you could...

```
for year in 1998 1999 2000 2009 2010 2011
do  declare -a "y$year=($(printf "%s-$year " JF JFE RFS JBF JFI JMCB |
               tee /dev/fd/2 ))"
    year=y$year[@]; year=(${!year})
    echo "${#year[@]}"
done 2>&1; unset year
```

This is the output from the second command, but the first prints the same sans the 6 - which just indicates the array member count.

```
JF-1998 JFE-1998 RFS-1998 JBF-1998 JFI-1998 JMCB-1998 6
JF-1999 JFE-1999 RFS-1999 JBF-1999 JFI-1999 JMCB-1999 6
JF-2000 JFE-2000 RFS-2000 JBF-2000 JFI-2000 JMCB-2000 6
JF-2009 JFE-2009 RFS-2009 JBF-2009 JFI-2009 JMCB-2009 6
JF-2010 JFE-2010 RFS-2010 JBF-2010 JFI-2010 JMCB-2010 6
JF-2011 JFE-2011 RFS-2011 JBF-2011 JFI-2011 JMCB-2011 6
```

Remember that `declare` is a command and the `var$expand=(something $expand)` argument is just that - an arg. `declare`'s args are expanded in the same way as any other - which is not true of a `var$expand=$expand` statement. So you can indirectly `declare` in the same way you can indirectly `export` or whatever - the hardquotes you use are not necessary I think.

Answer (score 2):

**Convert the brace expansion to an array via `set --`.**

Then you have a simple two dimensional loop to construct your output:

```
set -- {JF,JFE,RFS,JBF,JFI,JMCB}
for year in {1998..2000} {2009..2011}; do
    printf "y%s: " $year
    for code do
        printf "%s-%s " $code $year
    done
    echo
done
```

Yields:

```
y1998: JF-1998 JFE-1998 RFS-1998 JBF-1998 JFI-1998 JMCB-1998
y1999: JF-1999 JFE-1999 RFS-1999 JBF-1999 JFI-1999 JMCB-1999
y2000: JF-2000 JFE-2000 RFS-2000 JBF-2000 JFI-2000 JMCB-2000
y2009: JF-2009 JFE-2009 RFS-2009 JBF-2009 JFI-2009 JMCB-2009
y2010: JF-2010 JFE-2010 RFS-2010 JBF-2010 JFI-2010 JMCB-2010
y2011: JF-2011 JFE-2011 RFS-2011 JBF-2011 JFI-2011 JMCB-2011
```